# How to return value from helper function back to server.js NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

For my project I have a server.js that calls a helper function place-search.js as shown below.

```js
var express = require('express');
var server = express.Router();

var placeSearch = require("./helpers/place-search");
var obj = "hello";

server.use(function(req, res, next) {
 console.log(req.method, req.url);
 next();
}); 

server.post('/', function(req, res) {
 /* get the object passed by the client's post request */
 obj = req.body;

 //console.log("Obj: " + obj);

 /* send the confirmation back to the client */
 res.status(200).send("body");
 placeSearch.placeSearch(obj);
});

module.exports.server = server;
```

Here is my place-search.js :

```js
var config = require("./config.js");
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var DistanceMatrix = require("./distance-matrix.js");
var GooglePlaces = Promise.promisifyAll(require("googleplaces"));
var googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces(config.apiKey, config.outputFormat);
var extract = require('./extract.js');
var combination = require('./combination_ver2.js');
var permutation = require('./permutation.js');

function placeSearch(obj) {

    console.log("Inside place search!");

    /**
     * Place search - https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearchRequests
     */
    var arr = [];
    var count = 0;
    var rad = obj["radius"];
    
    console.log("radius: " + rad);
    var loc = obj["location"];
    console.log("Location: " + loc);
    var mode = obj["mode"];

    var params = obj["params"];

    /* client's keywords */
    var arr;
    var ar = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < params; i++) {
        arr[i] = obj[i];
        console.log(arr[i]);
        var param = {
            location: loc,
            radius: rad,
            mode: mode,
            keyword: arr[i]
        };
        ar.push(param);
    }

    console.log("before promises");

    var promises = ar.map(function(name) {
        return googlePlaces.placeSearch(name, function(response) {
            arr.push(response);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(count++);
            //If all responses have been returned
            //Find combos and pass to distance-matrix
            if (count == ar.length) {
                var Matrix = new Array();
                var result = new Array();

                //to extract only lat and lng from arr.results
                //Matrix = extract.extract(arr);
                result = combination.combination(arr);

                // NOW RESULT IS THE ARRAY OF ALL COMBINATION

                // NOW RESULT IS THE ARRAY OF COMBINATIONS OF latlng pairs AND PASS IT TO FRONTEND
                /*result.forEach(function(combo, index) {
                    console.log("combo" + combo)
                    DistanceMatrix.distanceMatrix(mode, combo, result.length);
                });*/


                // IF YOU WANT TO SEE PERMUTATION
                //permutation.permutation(result);

                console.log("combination results: " + result);

            }

        })
    });

}

module.exports.placeSearch = placeSearch;
```

My problem is I do not know how to pass the result variable back to the server.js so that I can use that result as an input for another helper function. I can not for the life of me figure out how to do this. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see your placeSearch function returning anything at all right now, nor doing any kind of callback.  Your placeSearch function should expose a callback parameter, which then gets called once you have the answer you want to send back.

Your server file will then take action on that callback.  Abbreviating your code, it'd look something like this:

```
server.post('/', function(req, res) {
    /* get the object passed by the client's post request */
    obj = req.body;

    //console.log("Obj: " + obj);
    placeSearch.placeSearch(obj, function(error, data){
       /* send the data back to the client */
       res.status(200).send(data);
    }); 
});
```

To support that, your placeSearch function will have to call its callback when appropriate:

```
function placeSearch(obj, callback){

   /* all the stuff you do to assemble your data */
   // if (there_is_some_error):
   if(err) return cb(err);

   // when you have all your data available, no error has occurred
   return cb(null, data);
}
```

Something else you might notice is that your `ar.map` won't work as you seem to expect.  `ar.map` is a synchronous function, you're calling async code inside... not gonna work the way you think.  It's a bit long for this post, but you should look at the `async` library from npm to manage an array of asynchronous requests to collect one combined result.

Answer (score 0):

use callback your code looks like this:

```
function placeSearch(obj,callback) {

    console.log("Inside place search!");

    /**
     * Place search - https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearchRequests
     */
    var arr = [];
    var count = 0;
    var rad = obj["radius"];

    console.log("radius: " + rad);
    var loc = obj["location"];
    console.log("Location: " + loc);
    var mode = obj["mode"];

    var params = obj["params"];

    /* client's keywords */
    var arr;
    var ar = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < params; i++) {
        arr[i] = obj[i];
        console.log(arr[i]);
        var param = {
            location: loc,
            radius: rad,
            mode: mode,
            keyword: arr[i]
        };
        ar.push(param);
    }

    console.log("before promises");

    var promises = ar.map(function(name) {
        return googlePlaces.placeSearch(name, function(response) {
            arr.push(response);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(count++);
            //If all responses have been returned
            //Find combos and pass to distance-matrix
            if (count == ar.length) {
                var Matrix = new Array();
                var result = new Array();

                //to extract only lat and lng from arr.results
                //Matrix = extract.extract(arr);
                result = combination.combination(arr);

                // NOW RESULT IS THE ARRAY OF ALL COMBINATION

                // NOW RESULT IS THE ARRAY OF COMBINATIONS OF latlng pairs AND PASS IT TO FRONTEND
                /*result.forEach(function(combo, index) {
                    console.log("combo" + combo)
                    DistanceMatrix.distanceMatrix(mode, combo, result.length);
                });*/


                // IF YOU WANT TO SEE PERMUTATION
                //permutation.permutation(result);

                console.log("combination results: " + result);

                callback(null,result);
            }

        })
    });

}
```

in server.js:

```
server.post('/', function(req, res) {
    /* get the object passed by the client's post request */
    obj = req.body;

    //console.log("Obj: " + obj);

    /* send the confirmation back to the client */
    res.status(200).send("body");
    placeSearch.placeSearch(obj,function(err,result){
       if(!err){
console.log(result);
}
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're having trouble with the async operation. You'll want to `return` the promise from your place-search module. You'll also need to convert the callbacks from placeSearch into a promise.

EDIT: updated since `googlePlaces.placeSearch` doesn't return a promise

inside `placeSearch`

```
function placeSearch(obj) {
  //...
  var promises = ar.map(function(name) {
    var placeDefer = Q.defer();

    return googlePlaces.placeSearch(name, function(response) {
      placeDefer.resolve(response); // or placeDefer.reject if a failure occurs
    });
    return placeDefer.promise;
  });

  return promises;
}
```

and in your route:

```
// I'm going to just assume Q promise library here
var Q = require("q");

server.post('/', function(req, res) {
    /* get the object passed by the client's post request */
    obj = req.body;

    //console.log("Obj: " + obj);

    /* send the confirmation back to the client */
    res.status(200).send("body");

    Q.all(placeSearch.placeSearch(obj))
    .spread(function() {
      var places = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

      // possibly call res.status(200).send("body"); here?
      // only if you're trying to use the places in your response
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, despite using `var promises = `, it didn't look like anything was actually a promise.

Comment: I was assuming `googlePlaces.placeSearch` returned a promise.

Comment: Not if he's using the npm module as it appears.https://www.npmjs.org/package/googleplaces